# TypeDoc returns blank documentation for Express JS API

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typedoc

I'm trying to document my Express JS API using TypeDoc, but I get a rather empty documentation generated.
[image]

This is my API file structure

[image]

This is my tsconfig.json:

```json
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node", 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "typedocOptions": {
    "entryPoints": ["server.ts"],
    "out": "docs"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? All materials on the web point to adding the TypeDoc option {"mode": "modules}. But that's been deprecated. I would appreciate any guidance.

I ran `npx typedoc` and got empty documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the "**expand**" [entryPointStrategy](https://typedoc.org/api/enums/EntryPointStrategy.html) option, then add "**src/**" to your `entryPoints`, that is assuming all the API code you wish to document is within that directory. You can keep your "**server.ts**" in the `entryPoints` option or move it into your "**src/**" directory.
Here is an example:

```
{
  "entryPoints": ["src/"],
  "entryPointStrategy": "expand",
  "out": "./docs",
  "plugin": ["typedoc-theme-hierarchy"],
  "theme": "hierarchy",
  "name": "Node TypeScript API",
  "includeVersion": true,
  "readme": "none",
  "exclude": ["./src/tests/*"]
}
```

Visit npm for more info on [typedoc-theme-hierarchy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc-theme-hierarchy)